# Not getting the first value when using "array_search"

Tags: php, arrays

Here, I have two multi-dimensional array. As I want to find the value from first array if the value is there in second array or not.

First array:

```
$abc = array(
    array("fld_channel_selected_item_track_id" => 627905217),
    array("fld_channel_selected_item_track_id" => 616557954)
);
```

Second array:

```
$pqr = array(
    array(
        "fld_channel_item_track" => 627905217,
        "fld_channel_item_title" => "Tropical Fantasy"
    ),
    array(
        "fld_channel_item_track" => 616557954,
        "fld_channel_item_title" => "Bday Boys"
    )
);
```

So, I am searching if the first array value is there in second array value or not:

```
for($i = 0;$i < count($abc); $i++)
{   
    $pos = array_search($abc[$i]["fld_channel_selected_item_track_id"], array_column($pqr, 'fld_channel_item_track'));
    if($pos) 
    {   
        echo "<pre>";print_r($pqr[$pos]);
    }
}
exit;
```

The outout is:

```
<pre>Array
(
    [fld_channel_item_track] => 616557954
    [fld_channel_item_title] => Bday Boys
)
```

Here, I am not getting the first value in my output.

Where I am wrong in that?

Comment: Because if `$pos` is 0 it is considered __false__.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is `array_search` ([doc](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php)) return index -> in your case index 0 so `if ($pos)` fails...

> Returns the key for needle if it is found in the array, FALSE otherwise.

Need to compare result to FALSE

By the way, this will be better way t achieve what you need:

```
$a = array_column($abc, 'fld_channel_selected_item_track_id');
$b = array_column($pqr, "fld_channel_item_title", "fld_channel_item_track");
foreach($a as $searchId)
    if (isset($b[$searchId])) echo $b[$searchId] . PHP_EOL;
```

Answer (score 2):

array_search() returns the position if it found, else will return FALSE

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php

> Returns the key for needle if it is found in the array, FALSE otherwise.
>
> Warning
> This function may return Boolean FALSE, but may also return a non-Boolean value which evaluates to FALSE. Please read the section on Booleans for more information. Use the === operator for testing the return value of this function.

For the first value, it is actually found, but the result is 0

```
$pos = 0
```

So it will fail the if...else check

```
if ($pos) {
   // $pos = 0 is falsy
}
```

You need to perform a more explicit comparison

```
if ($pos !== FALSE) {
    // code here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**As already pointed by other answers that,**

we know that `array_search()` returns `index` value so for first loop it returns **0** and for second  it's **1** so when `if($pos)` is **0** it fails. But you can modify your exiting code with `in_array()` to achieve what you want. Let's try like below-

```
for($i = 0;$i < count($abc); $i++)
{ 
    $pos = in_array($abc[$i]["fld_channel_selected_item_track_id"], array_column($pqr, 'fld_channel_item_track'));
    if($pos) 
    {   
        echo "<pre>";print_r($pqr[$i]); // see the index I changed here
    }
}
```

**DEMO:** https://3v4l.org/HA9tA